# Adhoc connection between Ubuntu to Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, networking, adhoc

1. On one machine I created one adhoc network with manual setting. that mean not providing any manual IP addresses. And from another machine I am trying to connect that ad hock network.It is showing me that ad hock network in my wireless network list.But I am not able to connect. I tried with windows machine. from windows machine I tried to connect and its working fine.But with Ubuntu to Ubuntu its not connecting. Am I missing something. Need some help. Thank you.

   ```
   lo        no wireless extensions.

   vmnet8    no wireless extensions.

   wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"NEWNET"  
     Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Cell: F6:6A:64:3C:AD:59   
     Tx-Power=13 dBm   
     Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
     Power Management:off

   eth0      no wireless extensions.

   vmnet1    no wireless extensions.



   wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ec:55:f9:77:90:88  
     inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
     inet6 addr: fe80::ee55:f9ff:fe77:9088/64 Scope:Link
     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
     RX packets:142440 errors:0 dropped:1625 overruns:0 frame:0
     TX packets:82989 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
     collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
     RX bytes:58226725 (58.2 MB)  TX bytes:15528756 (15.5 MB)
   ```

Comment: Can you include the output of `iwconfig` and `ifconfig` in your question?

Comment: Yeah sure. I will add.

Answer (score 0):

Look for essid:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep -i 'essid'
```

release the ip:

```
sudo dhclient -r wlan0
```

connect to NEWNET:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 essid NEWNET
```

Assign IP:

```
sudo dhclient wlan0
```

Check results:

```
dmesg
```

Also consider looking at the results of `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` to see if there is any useful information in regards to network masks, radio channels, or the like that might not be matching up.